# Python CSV module - how does it avoid delimiter issues?

Tags: python, excel, csv, export-to-csv

I am using python's CSV module to output a series of parsed text documents with meta data. I am using the csv.writer module without specifying a special delimiter, so I am assuming it is delimited using commas. There are many commas in the text as well as in the meta data, so I was expecting there to be way more columns in the document rows, when compared to the header row.

What surprises me is that when I load the outputted file in Excel, everything looks exactly right. How does Excel know how to delimit this correctly??? How is it able to figure out which commas are text commas and which ones are delimiters?

Related question: Do people usually use CSV for saving text documents? Is this a standard practice? It seems inferior to JSON or creating a SQLite database in every sense, from long-term sustainability to ease of interpreting without errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the outputted CSV file in a text editor like Sublime, and what you'll probably see is the commas in the text have been escaped using an escape string (usually wrapped with a double quote).
This is defined in the CSV spec file here: https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4180

As for use of CSV files, they are in fact still surprisingly common mainly due to both legacy systems and the fact that they're just so quick and easy to deal with for most tasks.

Answer (score 1):

You shall inspect the real content of CSV file you have created and you will see, that there are ways to enclose text in quotes. This allows distinction between delimiter and a character inside text value.

Check csv module documentation, it explains these details too.